# Backbone.js: one nested JSON response or multiple JSON responses?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, nested, models

In my application, I have two types of data: groups that contain items, and the items themselves. Every item is assigned to a group, and empty groups may exist (and must be represented). This seems like a simple scenario, but I'm having trouble finding information on how to set up the models, views, and JSON responses in this case.

Would it be sensible to have both a group collection and an item collection, and include a separate JSON URL for each? The JSON responses would look like, for example:

```
[ { "id": 1,
    "name": "Group A"
  },
  { "id": 2,
    "name": "Group B"
  },
  { "id": 3,
    "name": "Group C"
  } ]
```

and

```
[ { "id": 1,
    "group_id": 1,
    "name": "Item A"
  },
  { "id": 2,
    "group_id": 1,
    "name": "Item B"
  },
  { "id": 3,
    "group_id": 2,
    "name": "Item C"
  } ]
```

In this case, how do you handle asynchronous loading of two JSON objects that are interrelated?

Or, should I combine this data on the server into a single JSON response? In this case, if it's feasible, is only one collection (e.g. groups) associated with a JSON URL, and is its model responsible for creating the items?

EDIT: The view will display multiple groups, with each group containing zero or more items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the pattern i've been using in my past projects

in your situation, I'd let the server return one `groups` json with items nested inside, eg:

```
[
  {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Group A',
    'items': [
      {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'item A'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'item B'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Group B',
    'items': [
      {
        'id': 4,
        'name': 'item D'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'Group C',
    'items': []  //emtpy
  }
]
```

and in your Backbone model, you can parse each individual nested items array to an `items` collection:

```
var Group = Backbone.Model.extend({
  parse: function (data) {
    data.items = new Items(data.items);
    return data;
  }
});
```

so when you initialize your collection, remember to pass {parse: true} to the options:

```
var groups = new Groups([...], {parse: true});
```

or you can override the constructor in the model to force parse to be always true:

```
var Group = Backbone.Model.extend({
  constructor: function(attributes, options) {
    options = options || {};
    options.parse = true;
    Backbone.Model.call(this, attributes, options);
  },

  parse: function () { ... }
});
```

I usually create a separate model with forced parse, and create models by extending that to avoid having to use this everywhere.

when, then in this collection, for each `group` you will have a nested Items collection,

```
group.get('items');   //is a backbone collection
```

you can pass it to subviews to render each individual item.

You can still maintain different routes in Items/Groups (no nested routes), and if you need to save/destroy each Item, the action won't interfere with its group, or other items.

a sample jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/4LNXz/

Answer (score 1):

not a question which can be answered in general, but you should keep in mind that every  request, is additional overhead which forces the user to wait for your app. so you should generally try to avoid if possible.

if you have the option to go with example 2, you probably should do so...

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you plan to use your data model in your views.

1. Are you planning to show one group per view? If yes, then it might suffice to have a collection of items. If no a collection of groups that contains a collection of items suits better.
2. Are you developing the backend as well? If yes, it obviously makes sense to structure it the same way as your data model. Which would mean a service for querying all groups and a service to query all items within a group. If no, you would need to add logic to populate your data model from the JSON, which is the less ideal case.

Or are you showing you data in a grid? In which case it might be perfectly fine to have all items in a flat JSON.

Comment: Thanks, Will. Yes, I'm planning to display multiple groups per view, with multiple items per group. So, regarding your first point, you're suggesting an Items collection associated with each group (as [described here](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-nested))? In response to your second point, it would seem like having multiple groups, and multiple Item collections per group would result in a lot of JSON requests. Knowing that there are multiple groups per view, does this affect your recommendation? Or is that still preferable to the alternative of adding logic for parsing the JSON?

Comment: The data representation would be somewhat grid-like. Actually, each group will act as a bin (probably just a stylized div) containing an arbitrary number of items.